# JDBC iso-8859-1 encoding

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, encoding, jtds

In my program, I'm connecting to a Microsoft SQL database using JTDS (http://jtds.sourceforge.net/). The encoding of my database is iso-8859-1. However, to send queries in Java, I have to use Strings (which are normally encoded with UTF). Is it possible to send a Query with a different encoding than UTF?

EDIT: The results are displayed wrong after I use INSERT or UPDATE. If I only select from the database, special characters are displayed right.

Comment: Eh... you have some misconceptions about character encoding. Are you experiencing any problems?

Comment: Some characters like "äöüß" are displayed wrong.

Comment: You mean when they are retrieved from the database? First you'll have to identify where the encoding going wrong, then you'll need to fix that. Read through the documentation for JTDS and see if you can specify the database encoding to use.

Comment: Sorry, I meant that the strings are stored wrong after INSERT or UPDATE.

Comment: Well, my advice still stands. How are the characters displayed? What do you get instead of 'ä'?

Comment: [Unicode is a superset](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin-1_Supplement_(Unicode_block)) of [Latin-1 (ISO 8859-1)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1). So if your Java strings contain only Latin-1 characters they should transfer properly through a JDBC driver to a database limited to Latin-1. As commenter suggested, you should learn the difference between character set (Unicode) and character encoding (UTF-8 etc.). Start with [this entertaining article by Joel Spolsky](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html).

Answer (score 2):

One outstanding design principle of java is that text, String, is always Unicode. In general you cannot even see that it is in Unicode, as only when getting byte you (should) indicate the encoding the bytes should be converted into. *So you would not need to do anything - ideally.*

The error can stem from:

- Hard coded literal strings in Java: the encoding of the java source must be the same
  as the encoding of the java compiler `javac`. *This can be tested by trying `\u00FC` instead of `ü`.*
- Driver settings
- Connection settings
- Database / table / column definitions
- False placed error: when outputting results, when inputting data

Try an INSERT of "\u00FC + ü" and a SELECT for a byte comparison. Dump the byte codes. (To evade console problems.)

```
Arrays.toString(string.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"));
```

Do ***not*** try repairs like `new String(s.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8")` - or so.

Should this find no problems the cause must be sought elsewhere.

BTW: better use Windows-1252 (Windows Latin-1) instead of ISO-8859 (Latin-1) as that allows some special chars like comma-like quotes (range 0x80 - 0xBF). HTML accepts Windows-1252 as
ISO-8859-1 too.

Answer (score 1):

The JDBC driver actually handles the conversion internally, *if* you are *not* simply creating inserts by concatenating Strings:

(This is bad, *never* do this)

```
String aValue = "äöü";
String insert = "INSERT INTO table VALUES('" + aValue + "')";
Statement s = connection.createStatement();
s.executeUpdate(insert);
```

Use a prepared statement (that also avoids security holes like SQL injection):

```
String aValue = "äöü";
String insert = "INSERT INTO table VALUES(?)";
PreparedStatement s = connection.prepareStatement(insert);
s.setString(1, aValue);
s.executeUpdate();
```

Edit: Also make sure that what you're trying to insert is really what you want to insert. For the german umlauts, there is more than one possible representation in unicode, e.g. ö can be represented as "\u00F6", but it can also (rarely, depending on source) be represented using combining diacritics (e.g "o\u0308" also looks like ö).

Answer (score 0):

When I connect to an Access database (.mdb) which is encoded with ISO-8859-1 I 
use this syntax:

```
String dbPath = "fakeDBPath.mdb";
String database = "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=" + dbPath + ";DriverID=22;READONLY=false}";

final Properties prop = new Properties();
prop.put("charSet", "ISO-8859-1");
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection( database, prop );
```

After I get the Connection I'm able to use Java strings withouth the need to specify any additional encoding.
Maybe JTDS supports a specific propertiy to set encoding.

For example, to insert data in the DB:

```
String cmd = "INSERT INTO Table (Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4) VALUES (1000,'àèìòù','é®þü','fake data');";
Statement s = DBTable_1.getStatement();
try
{
    int r = s.executeUpdate(cmd);
} catch ( SQLException ex )
{
    Logger.getLogger( Main.class.getName() ).log( Level.SEVERE, null, ex );
}
```

And to read from the DB:

```
String cmd = "SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Col2='àèìòù';";
Statement s = DBTable_1.getStatement();
try
{
  ResultSet r = s.executeQuery(cmd);

  while(r.next())
  {          
    System.out.println("Col2: " + r.getString(2) + " Col3:" + r.getString(3));
  }

} catch ( SQLException ex )
{
  Logger.getLogger( Main.class.getName() ).log( Level.SEVERE, null, ex );
}
```